# Printing out Unique Values From Several Tables in Reverse Chronological Order

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database with multiple tables, each of which have the same structure.  The structure is:

```
id INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, site VARCHAR(350) NOT NULL, votes_up BIGINT(9) NOT NULL, votes_down BIGINT(9) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id), UNIQUE (site)
```

The PHP code below prints out each unique "site" from across all the tables and sums the "votes_up" it has from all tables.  It then lists the top 25 values for "site" (based on total "votes_up") in descending order.

This code works great, but I would like to do the exact same thing based on create time in reverse-chronological order.  How do I do this?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
<?

mysql_connect("mysqlv10", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("bookfeather") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES");
$tables = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $tables[] = '`'.$row["Tables_in_bookfeather"].'`';

}

//$subQuery = "SELECT site, votes_up FROM ".implode(" UNION ALL SELECT site, votes_up FROM ",$tables);

$subQueryParts = array();
foreach($tables as $table)
    $subQueryParts[] = "SELECT site, votes_up FROM $table WHERE LENGTH(site)";
$subQuery = implode(" UNION ALL ", $subQueryParts);

// Create one query that gets the data you need
$sqlStr = "SELECT site, sum(votes_up) sumVotesUp
            FROM (
            ".$subQuery." ) subQuery
           GROUP BY site ORDER BY sum(votes_up) DESC LIMIT 25";
$result = mysql_query($sqlStr);

$arr = array(); 
echo "<table class=\"samples2\">";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename2"><a href="booklookup3.php?entry='.urlencode($row["site"]).'&searching=yes&search=search">'.$row["site"].'</a></td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row["sumVotesUp"].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
} 

echo "</table>";


?>
```

Comment: uh... how are you going to determine "chronology" when you don't have a date of any kind (that i can see... am i blind?)

Comment: You are right... do I need to add the date stamp somehow for "site"?

In another query, I am using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and CREATE_TIME to show tables created in reverse chronological order... is there a way to use that here?

Comment: No, table rows are not recorded in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, you will have to add a column which would store the time when the row was created. This column can be of type `INT` if you are going to store UNIX timestamps or `DATETIME` if you wish to use date strings. Also, if you don't want to do that, you can use `ORDER BY id DESC`, because auto-increment columns *most often* correspond to the chronological order, but that's not a stable solution, because when the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value runs out of the range of the `INT` data type, it starts using unused values (e.g. from deleted rows).